# Akka Stream how to determine inside GraphStageLogic whether it failed

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I have a network of nodes all implemented using custom `GraphStageLogic`. I can't find any API to determine when a stage throws an exception (e.g. `IllegalArgumentException` for `Cannot pull port`). The only thing Akka does is fail the down stream connections. What I need to determine is, for example in `postStop` or through a callback, when a node shuts down due to runtime exception, and propagate that information to a `Promise` that monitors the state of the entire system. Using `withAttributes(supervisionStrategy)` does not have any effect, either. It seems bewildering to me that there is no way to monitor exceptions thrown inside a `GraphStageLogic`? `failStage` is final like basically the entire API of `GraphStageLogic`.

Answer (score 0):

Using decider when defining the ActorMaterializer used for materializing the Graph should work:

```
implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer(
      ActorMaterializerSettings(actorSystem).withSupervisionStrategy(decider))
```

where decider is the typical

```
val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
  case e: IllegalArgumentException => ....
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, didn't work for me. If an exception is thrown in any node, I don't get that decider to be invoked.

Comment: Hey there, could you provide some sample code reproducing this? Hard to judge from the information provided here